# JQplot tooltip for multiple y axes

Tags: tooltip, axis, jqplot

For a JQplot chart with 2 y axes, I am able to set the tooltip but when i hover over a datapoint i need to know to which y axis the tooltip belongs. I need this so that i can display the tooltip after multiplying with the appropriate scale factor. The code i tried is shown below. I thought y will be null when we hover over a data point belonging to y2 axis. But y is never null.

```
 $("#"+sTargetId).bind('jqplotcustomDataMouseOver', 
                   function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {    
                     var chart_left = $("#"+sTargetId).offset().left,
                     chart_right = ($(window).width() - ($("#"+sTargetId).offset().left + $("#"+sTargetId).outerWidth())),
                     chart_top = $("#"+sTargetId).offset().top,
                       x = oPlot.axes.xaxis.u2p(data[0]),
                       y = oPlot.axes.yaxis.u2p(data[1]),
                       y2 = oPlot.axes.y2axis.u2p(data[1]);;
                       if(y===null|| y===undefined){   //this condition doesnt work
                       var tooltipDataYaxis = data[1]*scaleYaxis1;
                       var sYDisplay = this.sYAxis1MeasureName;
                       $('#tooltip').css({left:chart_left+x, top:chart_top+y, marginRight:chart_right});
                       }
                       else{

                        tooltipDataYaxis = data[1]*scaleYaxis2;
                        sYDisplay = this.sYAxis2MeasureName;
                        $('#tooltip').css({left:chart_left+x, top:chart_top+y2, marginRight:chart_right});
                       }

                          $('#tooltip').html(

                                 '<span style="font-family: Arial;font-size:'+sTooltip+';font:bold;color:#000000;">'+ sYDisplay+': ' + tooltipDataYaxis +'</span>');
                         $('#tooltip').show();
                   });

        $("#"+sTargetId).bind('jqplotcustomDataUnhighlight', 
                 function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
                     $('#tooltip').empty();
                     $('#tooltip').hide();
                 });


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable seriesIndex will help to identify which series the tooltip belongs to. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was just playing with jqplot for the first time. quite fun.

In the highlighter plugin jqplot.highlighter.js
I extended it on line 336

elem.html(str **+ " component:"+neighbor.data[2]**);

You might use Chrome developer tools to get the data model at this point and look at the contents of the neighbor object.
(scope variables > Local > neighbor > data )

That's how I did it anywho. Hope it helps.